# Почему z-index не работает в данном примере?

Tags: html, css

```css
.progressbar {
 counter-reset: step;
}

.progressbar li {
 list-style-type: none;
 float: left;
 width: 33.33%;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
}

.progressbar li:before {
 content: counter(step);
 counter-increment: step;
 line-height: 30px;
 font-family: Nova-Bold;
 color: #12c412;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 border: 2px solid #12c412;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
 border-radius: 50%;
    background: white;
    z-index: 2;
}

.progressbar li:after {
 content: '';
 width: 100%;
 height: 1px;
 background: #000;
 position: absolute;
 top: 15px;
 left: -50%;
    z-index: 1;
} 

.progressbar li:first-child:after {
 content: none;
}

.type {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="type">
  <ul class="progressbar">
   <li class="active">Step 1</li>
   <li>Step 2</li>
   <li>Step 3</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: Наверно, потому что у :before нет position:relative, не?

Answer (score 3):

добавьте  для ::before position:relative
z-index работает там где position не static, a - relative, absolute, fixed

```css
.progressbar {
 counter-reset: step;
}

.progressbar li {
 list-style-type: none;
 float: left;
 width: 33.33%;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
}

.progressbar li:before {
 content: counter(step);
 counter-increment: step;
 line-height: 30px;
 font-family: Nova-Bold;
 color: #12c412;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 border: 2px solid #12c412;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
 border-radius: 50%;
    background: white;
    position:relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.progressbar li:after {
 content: '';
 width: 100%;
 height: 1px;
 background: #000;
 position: absolute;
 top: 15px;
 left: -50%;
    z-index: 1;
} 

.progressbar li:first-child:after {
 content: none;
}

.type {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="type">
  <ul class="progressbar">
   <li class="active">Step 1</li>
   <li>Step 2</li>
   <li>Step 3</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```